# how to show html content inside html page

Tags: html, iframe

i know i can have iframe in a html page, say parent.htm, and i can have something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img alt="http://localhost/images/header.png" src="http://localhost/images/header.png" width=700px height=100px />
        <iframe src="Child.htm"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

But can i put html directly into iframe rather than pointing it to a file (child.htm).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cant only browsers that do not support frames will show the contents

> The information to be inserted inline is designated by the src
>   attribute of this element. The contents of the IFRAME element, on the
>   other hand, should only be displayed by user agents that do not
>   support frames or are configured not to display frames.

[From W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5)

Answer (score 1):

Use a div, create html into it. Then set a size to the div and use overflow:auto to create scrollbar (like an iframe)

Comment: can i do something like this <html><div style="do what u said"> and here i can have entire webpage content </div></html> .............can i do something like above?